# Modeling Lines still rendered issue

Tags: modeling, rendering

I do not know why the modeling lines of this ship turret I am working upon are still visible when I render them.   Can someone why and how to remove them from render?   The rest of the ship as you can see is fine.  Thanks
[image]
[image]

Comment: first of all, you are in render preview, not in actual render and I am sure there won't be visible in final render... secondly you are probably making those parts with some addon? Is it using modifiers? Can you share more information about that object? It also may be object properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your object, navigate to Object Properties (orange square) and check this option:

[image]

Is wireframe active? If yes, deactivate it, problem solved

Comment: Wireframe was active.  I removed it and the lines went off.  Thanks.  I am plating the turret with a plates generator addon which had wireframe display on.

Comment: great, it is a good thing for things like that when you can see those lines always visible, some people prefer it this way

Comment: @ronin074 As MikoCG said in the question's comment, this is only a render preview, which is why there are also overlays shown like you can see the grid and the 3d cursor and things like cameras and lights. If you turn off overlays in render preview, these will all be invisible - and the wireframe as well.